# Site Column Not Displaying in List - SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-column, sharepoint-list

I created a site column in a Content Type that's used by a List.  The site column is listed with others from the same Source (Content Type). After that, the new site column is nowhere to be found: I expect to see it when creating a new item, but nothing. How do I get the new column to surface in the new/edit/update list forms?

Comment: Are you using a custom infopath form or the Out of the box Sharepoint list form?

Comment: I am using an out-of-the-box SharePoint List form.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set this content type as the default content type to the list ?
Go to list settings - advanced settings - > Allow management of content types - > Yes 
Go back to list settings - > change the default content type to your custom content type.
Now try adding/editing the list item.

Comment: Yes, the content type IS is the default content type for this particular list, we've been using it for several years.  I added a site column to said content type like all others, nothing special about it.